# How does metaplex candymachine works?

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, candymachine

[Metaplex candymachine docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/overview)  doesn't fully explain what in fact candymachines are and that's what I'm wondering.

When I create a candymachine, am I creating a new solana program  with those set of rules?
Or when I create a candymachine I'm just using the metaplex solana program to create it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a candy machine you are using the Metaplex candy machine Program. It initialises your candy machine account for you (with your own candy machine id), which contains your specific configuration like image pathes.

If you want more information it might be helpful to get information what exactly you are trying to learn.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, but I think you answered: when I create a candymachine, am I creating an account, or a program (smart contract)

Comment: Yeah then you got your answer already. You are creating an account